# an expansion in terms of norm and inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove the following inequality in $\mathbb{R}^n$

> For any $s\geq2$ there exists some constant $C(s)>0$ such that
> $$|y|^s>|x|^s+s|x|^{s-2}\langle x,y-x\rangle+\frac{C(s)}{2^s-1}|y-x|^s$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Here $|\cdot|$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denote the usual norm and inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ respectively.

I was initially thinking to use convexity of the map $x\mapsto|x|^s$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $$|y|^s\leq2^{s-1}(|x|^s+|y-x|^s)$$ But the inequality is in reverse order of what is required, also I have no idea to bring the inner product into picture. I have a intuition of the Taylor's expansion, but I am not very sure.

Any help is appreciated.